# Simple C++ file reading program only returns garbage

Tags: c++

I'm a beginner programmer and I'm having an issue that I'm sure is just caused by a stupid mistake but I for the life of me can't figure out what it is. I've tried searching solutions on this site but none of the remedies I found worked for my problem

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    ifstream inputFile;
    float num;
    inputFile.open("numbers.txt");
    inputFile >> num;
    cout << num << endl;
    inputFile >> num;
    cout << num << endl;
    inputFile >> num;
    cout << num << endl;
    inputFile >> num;
    cout << num << endl;
    inputFile >> num;
    cout << num << endl;

    inputFile.close();

    return 0;
}
```

So it's a simple code, and I'm reading the textbook I have verbatim on what to do but whenever I run the code it just churns out garbage versus the numbers.txt file I created using a different program.

If anyone can tell me where my mistake is, or tell me where to look up this problem I'd appreciate it. Thanks in advance

Edit: I used a different code to create the file and I can confirm that the file was created successfully in .txt format

Comment: Before reading from a file always check that the file `is_open()`.

Comment: You never tested if the file was opened correctly, neither you test if you input operations succeed.

Comment: okay, so I used is_open() to test whether the file is opening, and I am getting my error message back saying that there is an error opening the file. What do I do to ensure the file is opening?

Comment: Try to write in some known location with the following flags.Writing and reading string of varied length makes things complicated and chances of loading jargons in such cases is high ,so go for POD. inputFile.open("c:\\temp\\numbers.txt",std::if stream::in);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check if the file is opened correctly. Add the below code  after  `inputFile.open("numbers.txt");`

```
if(inputFile.fail())
{
    cerr<< "Error Opening File" << endl;
    exit(1);
}
```

Also try giving the absolute path of the file if there is an error in opening the file.

Comment: Alright I tried your code and also went ahead and made an if else statement using is_open() like Nathan Oliver said and I do get my error message popping up. 

I also copy and pasted the complete file location as: C:\Users\enjoy\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\ConsoleApplication6\ConsoleApplication6\numbers.txt.

Still no joy

Comment: Can you post the contents of numbers.txt

Comment: Yes sir

12.6
 10.4
 3.54
 10.61
 3.45

Each number is on its own separate line

Comment: Tried with the same set. It is working fine for me. Just for testing this piece, create another file manually with this input and try if it gives the desired result. I suspect the program which is creating numbers.txt

Comment: I created another file manually and I still get the error message. So I'm definitely confused at what I'm missing. Thanks for all the help anyway!